# Backbone - Get user's selected data from DOM or Collection

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I have one **Backbone Collection** (named *`themeCollection`*) which items are listed on the webpage (DOM). The user can select one item from that list. I need to save user's selected item into the database together with other information. It comes out two ways from my head to implement this feature.

[image]

#### 1) Get the selected list item from the DOM (by jquery)

```
addCard: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var formData = {};

            // Get data from the form
            $( '#modal-new-card form' ).children( 'input' ).each( function( i, el ) {
                if ( $(el).val() != '' ) {
                    formData[ el.id ] = $(el).val();
                }
                $(el).val('');
            });


            // Get selected listed item from the DOM.
            formData['theme'] = this.$el.find('div.colorSelected').attr('color');

            // Code for saving into the database
            // ...

        }
```

#### 2) Get the selected list item from the Backbone Collection

```
addCard: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = {};

        $( '#modal-new-card form' ).children( 'input' ).each( function( i, el ) {
            if ( $(el).val() != '' ) {
                formData[ el.id ] = $(el).val();
            }
            $(el).val('');
        });

        formData['theme'] = this.themeCollection.findWhere({selected: true});
    }
```

The first way seems to me a little awkward. It touches DOM so it closely coupled upon the DOM. That's not good. Whenever the `CSS class` is changed, my app would be stopped working.

The second way would be a little more jobs to be done. I have to change *`themeModel's`* selected attribute to be *`true`* whenever the user clicks. When changing, I also have to set `false` to selected attributes of all other models in the collection.

Which way would be the better choice? If you have any other ways, please share me and suggest me.

Comment: I would set the whole thing up as a Backbone model, setup change events on the inputs, and update the model when things are changed.  When save is pressed I would save the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you need to learn more about Backbone, but I'll try to help...

---

You should be using a `Model` for maintaining the form data and add events via `View` to update model when things change. Upon submit, you can call `model.toJSON()` to save to the DB.

```
var NewCard = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        question: '',
        explanation: '',
        color: 'Blue'
    }

})
```

Then setup a collection to hold the colors to select

```
var colors = new Backbone.Collection([
  {color: 'Blue'},
  {color: 'Gray'}
]);
```

#### [Here is a working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWPBxP)

[image: preview]

The example is far from complete, but should give you a picture.

Comment: Thanks very much for your effort to show me the correct way. Let's me try.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that you shouldn't store it like Collection.

If it's only about choosing a color, it's better store it as model attribute (`{"theme": "purple"}`) and then send this model to server.

Markup:

```
<input type="radion" name="theme" value="yellow">
<input type="radion" name="theme" value="purple">
```

Your view:

```
function changeTheme() {
  var cardData = this.$el.serializeArray(); // jQuery just for brevity

  this.model.trigger('THEME_CHANGE', cardData);
}

Backbone.Collection.extend({
  tagName: 'form',

  events: {
    'change [name="theme"]': changeTheme
  }
});
```

Model just listen for `THEME_CHANGE` and process data.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. But, it's more than ColorName. I just try to simple my program on the question.